# comparing norms of tensor product of two Hilbert spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

Suppose $H_1$ and $H_2$ are two Hilbert spaces with dimension $n$ and $m$, for $ x \in H_1 \otimes H_2$

consider $$\|x\|_\pi = \inf \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n \|a_i\| \|b_i\| : x = \sum_{i} a_i \otimes b_i \right\}$$
where $x \in A \otimes B$.

$ \|a\otimes b\|_{2}^2 =\langle a \otimes b,a\otimes b\rangle = \langle a,a\rangle_1 \, \langle b,b\rangle_2 \quad \mbox{for all } a \in H_1 \mbox{ and } b \in H_2 $
 respectively.

**Questions:**
1. We know norms on finite dimensional spaces are equivalent. Hence there are $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $$
c_1\|x\|_2
  \leq \|x\|_\pi 
  \leq c_2\|x\|_2
   $$ since $\|x\|_\pi$ is largest cross norm so $c_1$ can be taken equal to $1$. what about $c_2$

2.What about when $H_1$ and $H_2$ are arbitrary Hilbert spaces, are these two norm equivalent?

3. Where can I know more about such comparing norms on tensor of Hilbert spaces. (any book or article)

thanks, and pardon me for poor English.

Answer (score 5):

The norms are equivalent if and only if $\min(\dim(H_1),\dim(H_2))<\infty$.

One way to think about this is to dualize. The space of bounded linear functionals on $(H_1 \otimes H_2, \Vert\cdot\Vert_\pi)$ can be identified naturally with the space of bounded linear maps from $H_1^*$ to $H_2$. On the other hand, the space of bounded linear functionals on $(H_1 \otimes H_2, \Vert\cdot\Vert_2)$ can be identified naturally with the space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators $H_1^*\to H_2$. If both $H_1$ and $H_2$ are infinite-dimensional then there are bounded linear maps $H_1^*\to H_2$ that are not Hilbert-Schmidt, e.g. the "identity map on $\ell_2$" if both $H_1$ and $H_2$ are separable.

A good source to learn about tensor norms on Banach spaces is Ryan's book *Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces*, or if you want something more condensed and more advanced, the classic book of Defant and Floret.

Comment: Excuse me @Yemon choi, It is my question but I cannot access my account, your answer is great and accepted. thank you very much.

Comment: Just a minor detail, but googling suggests that the precise title of the book by Ryan is *Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces* (unless it's a different book).

Comment: @July Oops, you are completely correct. I was looking at my bookshelf and somehow conflated two titles of adjacent books :)