# norm of operator between matrix algebras equipped with trace norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

‎Let $M_i$ stands‎
‎for the algebra of $d_i\times d_i$ matrices with $\|T\|=d_i‎
‎\|T\|_1=d_i (trace{(T^\ast T)}^{\frac{1}{2}})$‎, ‎and $M_{ij}$‎
‎stands for the algebra of $d_i d_j\times d_i d_j$ matrices with‎
‎$\|T\|=d_i d_j \|T\|_1$‎. ‎ ‎The norm-decreasing maps‎
‎$$\rho_{i,j}:M_i\hat{\otimes} M_j \rightarrow M_{ij}; $$ 
$\rho_{i,j}(A\otimes B)=\left(\begin{matrix}A_{11}&\ldots&A_{1i}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\A_{i1}&\ldots&A_{ii}\end{matrix}\right) \otimes \left(\begin{matrix}B_{11}&\ldots&B_{1j}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\B_{j1}&\ldots&B_{jj}\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}A_{11}B&\ldots&A_{1i}B\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\A_{i1}B&\ldots&A_{ii}B\end{matrix}\right)‎$
gives a bijection between $M_i\hat{\otimes} M_j$ and $M_{ij}$. What's the norm of $\rho^{-1}_{i,j}$?

Comment: Why $M_i$  is an algebra?

Comment: I think a similar question may have been asked before on MathOverflow. Assuming that $\hat{\otimes}$ denotes the Banach space projective tensor product and not the operator space projective tensor product, the question boils down to a comparison between $({\mathbb C}^m \hat\otimes {\mathbb C}^n)\hat\otimes({\mathbb C}^m \hat\otimes {\mathbb C}^n)$ and  $({\mathbb C}^{mn})\hat\otimes({\mathbb C}^{mn})$

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan You can find it if you search trace class....

Comment: @YemonChoi, I searched but didn't find. May I ask, more explanasion?

Comment: Reza, you could try the sources I mention in my answer to one of your old questions: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222649/comparing-norms-of-tensor-product-of-two-hilbert-spaces More directly relevant is this answer by Peter Michor to someone else's question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211668/comparing-norms-on-tensor-products-of-matrices/211692#211692